# Java/Sql: return an average from a specific column problem

Tags: java, sql, mysql, jdbc

I'm using embedded SQL with Java. I have a simple table where I want to return an average from the column that contains temperatures. I tried to use **ResultSet** but it wasn't successful, I think this may be because average returns just a single data not a set. I tried to google it and look on the sun website documentation but no luck. Even my teacher couldn't remember how to do it : )

```
ResultSet aveTemp = stat.executeQuery("SELECT AVG(T_TEMP) FROM TrailTracker"); 
System.out.println("avg temp is " + aveTemp);
```

It outputs: **avg temp is com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@16897b2**

I know sql pretty well, but embedded with Java is new to me. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Even my teacher couldn't remember how to do it`. I would say WOW!!!

Comment: Haha I know... It's ok I like to learn on my own I understand better. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select avg(T_TEMP) from TRAILTRACKER"); 
if(rs.next())
    System.out.println("avg temp is " + rs.getFloat(1));
```

Remember the index starts with `1` for `ResultSet`. And you must call `next()` before trying to get any value. And yes, `ResultSet` is null-safe, means it will not be `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ResultSet aveTemp = stat.executeQuery("SELECT AVG(T_TEMP) FROM TrailTracker"); 
if (aveTemp.next()) {
    System.out.println("avg temp is " + aveTemp.getFloat(1)); 
}
```

It gets the float value from the first column of the result set. You can't just output the result set as this will invoke the toString method, which will return the class name followed by @ followed by the hex representation of the hashCode.

If you need to format the float to a certain number of decimal places, consider use of a [Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: I just tried it... I get exception: Before start of result set.

Comment: You need `getNext()` first. `if (aveTemp.getNext()) System.out.println("avg temp is " + aveTemp.getFloat(0)); `

Comment: There is no pop-up option for     getNext()    when you press the dot.

Comment: I can retrieve velocity column which is also a DECIMAL(5,2) type $ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TrailTracker);

Comment: Got it!! ( sorry not sure how to format the code, my first post) But here's what changes I made:                                     aveTemp.next();    System.out.println("avg temp is " + aveTemp.getDouble(1));